# Заполнения массива POST

Tags: post, php, массивы

Есть страница с формой списком товара. мне нужно получить названия товара и количество.

```
<input type="text" class="spinner-input form-control"  name="count" value="0">
 <input name="name_product" type = "hidden" value = "<?=$item['name'];?>">
```

таких полей формируется штук 10-15.

```
$suppliers_data = array();
$suppliers_data['count'] = $this->input->post('count');
$suppliers_data['name'] = $this->input->post('name_product');
```

тут якобы я получаю данные и заполняю массив
но когда делаю echo,print_r у меня выводиться данные с последнего поля.
Я так предполагаю тут нужно куда то цикл засунуть..но у меня ничего не получилось..
вообще мне их нужно потом в бд засунуть, но для проверки использую вывод echo,print_r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> таких полей формируется штук 10-15

```
<input name="name_product[]" type = "hidden" value = "<?=$item['name'];?>">
```

Теперь это массив, ключевой момент в имени инпута `name_product[]`, теперь и `print_r()` можно выполнять!

**UPD для далеких**

Из комментария:

> когда будет прохордить цикл по
> созданию этих форм

```
//$query = тут Sql запрос
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo '<input name="name_product[]" type = "hidden" value = "'.$item['name'].'">';
}

//После отправки на сервер
print_r($_POST['name_product']);
```

Comment: что за бред!!! во первых если и записать то так <?=$name_product[];?>а во вторых когда будет прохордить цикл по созданию этих форм он мне создаст кучу массивов даже не массивов мотомучто его еще обявить нужно

Comment: по сути мне нужно вытащить данные как из базы данных, только там за меня делает все функции, а тут хз как

Comment: Вы меня не правильно понили у меня есть файл вида
там  цикл foreach мне все делает из базы все выводит. 
потом я например заполняю таблици с и отправляю в обработчик
где строки 
$suppliers_data = array();
$suppliers_data['count'] = $this->input->post('count');
$suppliers_data['name'] = $this->input->post('name_product');
их ловят! но приходит только данные с последней строки 
а мне нужны все данные словить в один масив

Comment: > Вы меня не правильно понили у меня есть файл вида там цикл foreach мне все делает из базы все выводит. потом я например заполняю таблици с и отправляю в обработчик..

чёрт, мой мозг!